# Oauth2.0 server installation

Tags: java, rest, jboss, oauth-2.0

I have created rest webservice and configured oauth2.0 by following the below link  https://github.com/MinchuckSasha/SpringRestSecurityOauth. I deployed my web service on jboss application server.

I got it working i am getting access tokens and everything.

That's for a single webservice i configured oauth2.0, Now i want install Oauth2.0 server on jboss, so that i can register my other api's.

I have been researching from google, stackoverflow and othersites but didn't get any documentation.

Can anyone please help me where i can find related information ??

Thanks in advance....

Comment: An OAuth authentication server provides authentication and access tokens, but you said you are already getting access tokens.  Where are you getting the tokens from now?  I'm not clear on what you are trying to do, but I'd start with the Keycloak documentation.

Comment: https://github.com/MinchuckSasha/SpringRestSecurityOauth. This link contains code for a webservices which is configured with oauth2.0 that is working with tokens and all, that doesn't have anything to do with my question i would like to install oauth2.0 on jboss server, i am serching if anyone can provide any related documentation for that..

Comment: http://www.keycloak.org/documentation-2.1.0.html

Comment: @Rand i saw the keycloak documentation, it seems to be similar to oauth. But is there anything specific to oauth2 installation..

Comment: Looks like Keycloak sets itself up as the auth server, and its configuration is managed by the admin application.  Here's a document that describes configuring the auth server and deploying that configuration to your application: http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/keycloak/introduction-to-keycloak